# Porting UI from Windows XAML to Xamarin.Forms XAML

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a XAML file that I have developed for Windows Universal app.

```
  <ItemsControl x:Name="parentItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}"
            ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ParentsDataTemplate}" ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label x:Name="textBlock2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Text}" IsEnabled="False" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="30" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF"/>
```

When I port this into `Xamarin.Forms` (I am using Xamarin plugin on VS2015)
I get the following error.

**Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ItemsControl' could not be found**

Is there something that corresponds to `ItemsControl` in the same way as `Label` corresponds to `TextBlock`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ListView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) is probably the closest control to ItemsControl.

Comment: Is `ItemsView` same as `ItemsControl` ?